# Unity NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:22)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Sou novo no unity e ja rescrevi o codigo e de acordo com o tutorial que vi mas nao resolve

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ForceMultiplier = 3f;
    public float maximumVelocity = 3f;


    void Start()
    {

    }

    
    void Update()
    { 
      var HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude <= maximumVelocity){

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(HorizontalInput * ForceMultiplier, 0, 0));


      }
    }
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Hazard"))
        {
          Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Faça uma verificação se o GameObject onde está destinado seu script tens o componente Rigidbody.

Após fazer essa verificação e confirmar que ele é um componente no GameObject, destine o GetComponent no Start da seguinte maneira...

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start(){
   rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

Quando o GameObject for ativo em cena ele buscara o componente ***Rigidbody*** dentro do componente pai.

Caso houver a necessidade de consultar um Rigidbody em um GameObject filho, você terá que usar o seguinte código.

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start(){
   rb = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>();
}
```

Outra forma é você deixar esta variável como pública e linkar ela diretamente pelo inspector, arrastando o GameObject onde contem o Rigidbody, desta maneira não será necessário dar um GetComponent pelo script.

Depois de ter estes passos em mente vamos para o seu código...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ForceMultiplier = 3f;
    public float maximumVelocity = 3f;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    { 
      var HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= maximumVelocity){

        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(HorizontalInput * ForceMultiplier, 0, 0));


      }
    }
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Hazard"))
        {
          Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente recomendo você a não usar GetComponent. Ao invés disso, declare a variável do tipo que você quer, exemplo : Você está dando um Getcomponent no Rigidbody do objeto na qual essa classe está, faça assim [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb = default;. Ao salvar esse código, na unity vai aparecer um campo pedindo "Qual objeto com Rigidbody eu pego ?", você arrasta o objeto que tem o rigidbody pra esse lugar e salva. No código, ao invés de você usar um GetComponent().velocity.magnitude você vai usar um rb.velocity.magnitude. As vantagens de você fazer isso é que o seu código não vai ficar buscando o objeto que tem esse componente várias vezes, ainda mais que você está chamando no Update, o Update vai buscar 30 ou 60 vezes por segundo esse objeto.

Vou refazer seu código como exemplo:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ForceMultiplier = 3f;
    public float maximumVelocity = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb = default;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    
    void Update()
    { 
      var HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= maximumVelocity){

        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(HorizontalInput * ForceMultiplier, 0, 0));


      }
    }
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Hazard"))
        {
          Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

O [SerializeField] serve para você tornar uma variável privada visível no editor (Unity).